# Access value of JSON in JS Controller

Tags: json, lightning-web-components, js-controller

I received value from Apex  as,

{"data":{"Id":"a002E00000ZKKbGQAX","Name":"FCS Group","Frequency__c":"Monthly",}}

and I want to fetch the value of frequency, Below is the code I tried,

this.strtest=JSON.stringify(data);//outpu is as shown json format
console.log('data=='+this.strtest.data);undefined

Answer (score 2):

Im going to repeat myself here:

@Vanaja -  I would strongly recommend you go through the LWC documentation:

- [Call Apex Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/apex)

and to complete the [trailheads on LWC's](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-lightning-web-components) + ramp up your Javascript skills.

```
this.strtest=JSON.stringify(data);//outpu is as shown json format
```

the statement above is not true,  JSON.stringify is NOT a JSON object,

```
console.log('data=='+this.strtest.data);undefined
```

So, it is normal you cant access it as if it were a JSON object, Strings dont have key values(properties) thus they are not accessible.

Comment: better you can suggest her some code samples like how to parse it

Comment: I don't believe it would benefit anyone to provide code samples other than the ones included in the answer. If whoever reads this does not understand, it means they should probably go back to the basics in order to  understand what is going on.